# Domain user picker windows control?

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory, user-controls

I am creating an application that will let administrators to select
users from a custom domain group. I like to know whether there is windows api / windows control
that displays users in a given domain group. This UI control will allow listing of users from 
specific domain group in a selectable list like so:

domain\user1

domain\user2

Comment: No there is no such existing control under C#/.NET - You need to make one.

Comment: I've had to do this and I made my own.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction. Which api were you able to use?

Comment: [This](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/599697/Get-list-of-Active-Directory-users-in-Csharp) and [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C) might be helpful for learning how to work with AD from C#.